# Doubled Subtotal and grand total in checkout magento 1.5

Tags: magento, checkout, subtotal

After adding products in shopping cart, move to checkout page. when return back to Shopping Cart page again either clicking back link or top menu Cart item link, Subtotal and Grand Total price becomes doubled.

When adding new product to cart again subtotal and total price become doubled.

Earlier It was working fine, when move to cloud server, this issue raised.

I am using magento 1.5

Please anyone help me out, this issue is coming in live site.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Check this post out: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/227560/P15/. And check the sales_flat_quote_address table if there are to much address entries for the quote_id. I don't know how that happens but if there are more addreses it could happen that the quote is been doubled or trippled

chreers

Answer (score -1):

You have not provided enough information.

First of all, magento 1.5 does not have this bug. The bug you are facing is likely to come from custom work that was done on the project.

Is the site using an ajax cart? if so, follow the add to cart methods it uses.

Was there any custom work done on the cart controller?

other than that you really have not given enough information for people to attempt to answer this.